# Wordpress Comment Box on woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

can we activate same comment widget on woo-commerce product page which WordPress gives on post or pages. actually i want other users should be able to comment on others comment which is not allowed in review.

Comment: Hi, this wordpress query, how can this be a off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replies aren't disabled for reviews in woocommerce, but there is no output of a reply button. If you add one to the [`review.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/review.php) template via [`comment_reply_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link) - exemplary usage below - replies are possible.

**Code:**

```
$args = array(
    'reply_text' => 'Reply <span>&darr;</span>',
    'depth'      => '1',
    'max_depth'  => '5'
);
comment_reply_link( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce Reviews is not a commenting board. You cannot create comment threads and reply to each other. I think I've found a very good solution for you. There is a free wordpress plugin which adds a new tub "Discussions" and opens powerful commenting board to do any type of discussions and comments on product page. This plugin name is "WooDiscuz". This is the exact solution for you.

Here is that plugin page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woodiscuz-woocommerce-comments/

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce already comes with Product Reviews, which basically **are** WordPress comments.

You can activate those for each product via the *Product Data* metabox, therein the *Advanced* tab, and the *Enable reviews* checkbox.

You also can enable ratings on reviews, which you may find on the WooCommerce Settings page, *Products* tab, *Product Data*.

Comment: yup its there, i was looking for a reply option in this which has been activated using above (ialocin) code. thanks.

Comment: Reviews are good for users who have bought the product. Comments are useful for customers who are thinking about buying the product - i.e. a Q & A section for pre-sales